# Uploading Images Django Python

Tags: python, html, django, file, post

html:

```
<label for="image">Image</label>
Select a file: <input type="file" name="img">
```

Python:

```
image = (request.FILES.get("img"))
```

When I print `image` it prints `none`. If I just use `{{form}}` in between the `<form> </form>` tags it does send the image across to the view. However, for some specific reason I do not want to use the `{{form}}` method.

Any ideas how I can approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us how you define your view and your htnl form, to have a clear vision of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `<form>` has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, so it should look something like:

```
<form method="post" action="{URL}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input ...>
</form>
```